# Powershell script in Visual Studio: how to do post built events

Tags: powershell, visual-studio, msbuild

Working with Visual Studio Community 2022, I have a PowerShell script in my Solution (I installed PowerShellTools.2022.2023.8.0.vsix) and i'd like to do some post-build events (copying the script to some directory).

I tried to modify the psproj file and added a simple message event `<Message Text="test" Importance="high" />` but i don't get why it doesn't work: the build process end well but with no message displayed.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>6CAFC0C6-A428-4d30-A9F9-700E829FEA51</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyApplication</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyApplication</AssemblyName>
    <Name>Dumbow_Deploy</Name>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PostBuildScript>
    <Message Text="test" Importance="high" />
    </PostBuildScript>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Dumbow_Deployer.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio\PowerShellTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio\PowerShellTools.targets')" />
</Project>
```

In addition, i looked for some answer with the link http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003, but it's dead.

Any idea?

Comment: Which template did you use to create the project, the "PowerShell Script Project" template?

Comment: The namespace URL is not the MSBuild documentation. See [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022) instead.

Comment: `Message` is a task and tasks must be in a `target`. (I don't see either in the provided project code.) Add the following target to your project: `<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="Build"><Message Text="test" Importance="high" /></Target>`

Comment: The template was created by Visual Studio...
But, in the "Project Properties" interface, there is a "build event" tab where there are two text boxes: one for the PostBuild events, the other for the Prebuild Event. I added the message command to postbuild events textbox to see where it will be add in the pssproj file and go from there but it wasn't right...
I did as you said and it works. Thanks.

Comment: The "PowerShell Script Project" template is from the PowerShell Tools extension. The extension added the template to Visual Studio. The template doesn't implement a "complete" project. The author of the template left out all kinds of things. That's why the UI settings for Pre and Post build events don't work. (Naming projects with a file extension ending with `proj` is a convention, but the `.psproj` file extension specifically is not from Microsoft.)